# req.body.properties are undefined on router.put

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

hi i developed simple crud project and in that project get and post methods are ok but when i try to update some variable on mongoDB it just not working.

here is my angular code :

```
    updateUser(body:any,id:any){
          console.log(body); //in console i can see data clearly

          return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/:'+id , body, )
          .subscribe(response => console.log(response));

        }

    //in here body is a formgroup which named updateForm and has properties like username, password, status, imageUrl.
```

and my put code on nodejs:

```
    router.put('/user/edit/:id', function(req,res,next){  //USER INFO UPDATE 
      console.log("put 2");

     User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
      {    
          $set:  { username:req.body.username,
                   imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
                   status: req.body.status }
      },
      {
        new:true
      },
      function(err,updatedUser){
        if(err){res.send("error");}
        else { res.json(updatedUser); }
       }

       );
      console.log(req.params.id); //there is no problem on console
      console.log(req.body.imageurl);//undefined on console

    });
```

i have get and post methods very look like put they are working but put is not working because req.body.username or other thing are undefined on back-end in the front-end when i wrote updateForm.value i can see values of properties there is no problem about updateForm i hope i explained well .

edit:I foud solution by using new method let me share the new function with you guys :

```
updateUser(body:any,id:any){
      console.log(body);

      return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/' + id , body , {
        observe:'body',
        withCredentials:true,  
        headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')})
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    }
```

Comment: looks like a typo in your url it should be `return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/'+id , body, )` instead of `return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/:'+id , body, )`

Comment: is your image url is file ? or just a string ?

Comment: PLease show the data of `console.log(body);` in angular

Comment: this is how looks like consolo.log(body); in angular : {"username":"223","imageUrl":"123","password":"123123","status":"busy123"}
and my imgUrl not file it is just a string i use img tag for it not part of problem

Comment: Check out my answer , It will solve your problem . @Halid

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama bro i tried your method it works but still same problem exist which is in  mongoDB status:null imageUrl:null username:null after update

Comment: Come on the chat room, by clicking on the link given below in the comment. Will solve your issue there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your angular code. Change it as below:

```
 return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/' + id , body, )
          .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

And then check in your node application. It should work fine.

Comment: dude i am not gettin error about it i tried that my problem is about i cant use req.body.username or req.body.imageUrl  because when i try to console.log(req.body.username) it returns undefined and save as null to mongoDB

Comment: Have you written the console.log(req.body) in your node.js code? You have mentioned  only about the angular code and not node.js. Please post the console.log(req.body) output here.

Comment: as you see in my node.js code there is
 console.log(req.params.id);
 console.log(req.body.imageurl);

and it returns:
5d78e95d3b33e629acb2e0e7 -> this is id 
undefined   -> should be req.body.imageUrl

Comment: Yes but please post the output of the whole req.body so that the problem can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

Update your query with ,

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.params.id}, //or _id instead of id  
      {    
          $set:  { username:req.body.username,
                   imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
                   status: req.body.status }
      },
      {
        upsert: true
        new:true
      },
      function(err,updatedUser){
        if(err){res.send("error");}
        else { res.json(updatedUser); }
       }

       );
```

**AlSO** 

Remove `,` from you angular put request after body

```
updateUser(body:any,id:any){
    console.log(body); //in console i can see data clearly

    var sendBody = body
    return this.http.put(this.url+'/user/edit/:'+id , sendBody )
              .subscribe(response => console.log(response));

 }
```

Comment: there is no problem i am not getting error about it but i have just problem about req.body items because when i updated my data relevant variables turn null and i checked that then i saw when i write console.log(req.body.username) on the node.js it returns undefined thats way data turn to null on mongoDB i wanna solve that problem.

Comment: Did you updated in angular side as i mentioned above ? @Halid

Comment: @Halid, we understood your problem completely. To identify the cause of the problem we just need the output of req and req.body in your node application. It seems like a problem in the middleware or JSON object conversion.

Comment: here is full output of node.js 
put 2
5d78e95d3b33e629acb2e0e7
undefined
{}
(node:19244) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-

Comment: what is undefined? req.body? and what about the req? It means issue is not in the MongoDB query, the real issue is in the routing middleware.

Comment: undefined = > req.body.username
{}              =>  req.body 

the output of req is really long not fit even here but not error

Comment: Just mention clearly what is undefined. req.body or only req.body.username? Because you can't assume the req.body to be undefined if you get req.body.username undefined. Also it's fine if the output is long for req, just check in that object if you get the data that you passed from frontend.

Comment: undefined is req.body.username

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199311/discussion-between-sunny-parekh-and-halid). Please use this chat room for further discussion.